# htaccess mod_rewrite issue. trailing /

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using mod_rewrite to remove .php in links. However I am getting weird behavior when adding a trailing / to the rewritten link; external resources don't load. I was wondering if anyone can help mitigate this. Thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.allprepaidplans.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.allprepaidplans.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s(.*/)index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "external resources" you mean images, styles, scripts, etc. Then you need to make your links absolute or add a relative URI base:

```
<base href="/">
```